# Probability help question

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

A bag got X number of balls of which 4 are Red and some green balls. The probability of taken two Red balls are $\frac{1}{11}$.

Calculate the probability of randoml taken two different colour balls?

So here is the what I think

$$P(2 Red-balls)=\frac{1}{11}\tag1$$

$$\frac{4}{X}\times \frac{3}{X+1}=\frac{1}{11}\tag2$$

$$X^2+X-132=0\tag3$$

$$(X+12)(X-11)=0$$
$$X=11$$

But the teacher said it is $X=12$ balls

**I am not sure, where it is the mistake, can anyone point the way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the first draw, there are $X-1$ balls left.

$$\frac{4}{X}\times \frac{3}{X\color{red}-1}=\frac{1}{11}\tag2$$

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is correct. The problem is with your equation, it should be $x^2 - x - 132 = 0$ rather than $x^2 + x - 132 = 0$.

[image: calculations]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your work rather than posting a link to it since links may be deleted.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.